# How to scrape content between every two sibling <hr> tag?

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, css-selectors

It is hard to describe my real situation, so I directly lift website:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_intro.asp

The elements below is extremely long, you can just scan it quickly. As you open link, you will find every content block will be framed with two line (hr tag)with up and down side, so my purpose is to scrape every block content between two `hr` tag

(in fact,the difficulty is uncertain amount tags and fickle structure between every two hr tags)

How to achieve it?

````
<div class="w3-col l10 m12" id="main">
      <div id="mainLeaderboard" style="overflow:hidden;">
        <!-- MainLeaderboard-->

        <!--<pre>main_leaderboard, all: [728,90][970,90][320,50][468,60]</pre>-->
        <div id="snhb-main_leaderboard-0" data-google-query-id="CJmd77_F_OMCFUSJwgodAWAIsg"><div id="google_ads_iframe_/22152718/sws-hb//w3schools.com//main_leaderboard_0__container__" style="border: 0pt none;"><iframe id="google_ads_iframe_/22152718/sws-hb//w3schools.com//main_leaderboard_0" title="3rd party ad content" name="google_ads_iframe_/22152718/sws-hb//w3schools.com//main_leaderboard_0" width="468" height="60" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" srcdoc="" style="border: 0px; vertical-align: bottom;" data-google-container-id="d" data-load-complete="true"></iframe></div></div>
        <!-- adspace leaderboard -->

      </div>
<h1>Python <span class="color_h1">Tutorial</span></h1>
<div class="w3-clear nextprev">
<a class="w3-left w3-btn" href="/default.asp">❮ Home</a>
<a class="w3-right w3-btn" href="python_intro.asp">Next ❯</a>
</div>

<div class="w3-panel w3-info intro">
<p>Python is a programming language.</p>
<p>Python can be used on a server to create web applications.</p>
<a class="w3-btn w3-margin-bottom" href="python_intro.asp">Start learning Python now »</a>
</div>

<hr>

<h2>Learning by Examples</h2>
<p>Our "Show Python" tool makes it easy to learn Python, it shows both the 
code and the result.</p>

<div class="w3-example">
<h3>Example</h3>
<div class="w3-code notranslate pythonHigh"><span class="pythoncolor" style="color:black">
<span class="pythonkeywordcolor" style="color:mediumblue">print</span>(<span class="pythonstringcolor" style="color:brown">"Hello, World!"</span>)<span class="pythonnumbercolor" style="color:red">
</span> </span></div>
<a target="_blank" class="w3-btn w3-margin-bottom" href="showpython.asp?filename=demo_default">Run example »</a>
</div>

<p><b>Click on the "Run example" button to see how it works.</b></p>
<hr>

<h2>Python File Handling</h2>
<p>In our File Handling section you will learn how to open, read, write, and 
delete files.</p>
<p><a href="python_file_handling.asp">Python File Handling</a></p>

<hr>

<h2>Python Database Handling</h2>
<p>In our database section you will learn how to access and work with MySQL and MongoDB databases:</p>
<p><a href="python_mysql_getstarted.asp">Python MySQL Tutorial</a></p>

<p><a href="python_mongodb_getstarted.asp">Python MongoDB Tutorial</a></p>

<hr>

<h2>Python Exercises</h2>
<form autocomplete="off" id="w3-exerciseform" action="exercise.asp?filename=exercise_syntax1" method="post" target="_blank">
<h2>Test Yourself With Exercises</h2>
<div class="exercisewindow">
<h2>Exercise:</h2>
<p>Insert the missing part of the code below to output "Hello World".</p>
<div class="exerciseprecontainer">
<pre><input name="ex1" maxlength="5" style="width: 54px;">("Hello World")
</pre>
</div>
<br>
<button type="submit" class="w3-btn w3-margin-bottom">Submit Answer »</button>
<p><a target="_blank" href="exercise.asp?filename=exercise_syntax1">Start the Exercise</a></p>
</div>
</form>

<hr>
<div id="midcontentadcontainer" style="overflow:auto;text-align:center">
<!-- MidContent -->

  <!--<pre>mid_content, all: [300,250][336,280][728,90][970,250][970,90][320,50][468,60]</pre>-->
  <div id="snhb-mid_content-0" data-google-query-id="CNqS8r_F_OMCFUSJwgodAWAIsg"><div id="google_ads_iframe_/22152718/sws-hb//w3schools.com//mid_content_0__container__" style="border: 0pt none;"><iframe id="google_ads_iframe_/22152718/sws-hb//w3schools.com//mid_content_0" title="3rd party ad content" name="google_ads_iframe_/22152718/sws-hb//w3schools.com//mid_content_0" width="336" height="280" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" srcdoc="" style="border: 0px; vertical-align: bottom;" data-google-container-id="f" data-load-complete="true"></iframe></div></div>

</div>
<hr>

<h2>Python Examples</h2>
<p>Learn by examples! This tutorial supplements all explanations with clarifying examples.</p>
<p><a href="python_examples.asp" class="w3-button w3-light-grey">See All Python Examples</a></p>
<hr>

<h2>Python Quiz</h2>
<p>Learn by taking a quiz! This quiz will give you a signal of how much you know, or do not know, about Python.</p>
<p><a href="python_quiz.asp" class="w3-btn w3-blue">Python Quiz</a></p>
<hr>


<h2>Python Reference</h2>
<p>You will also find complete function and method references:</p>
<p><a href="python_reference.asp">Reference Overview</a></p>
<p><a href="python_ref_functions.asp">Built-in Functions</a></p>
<p><a href="python_ref_string.asp">String Methods</a></p>
<p><a href="python_ref_list.asp">List/Array Methods</a></p>
<p><a href="python_ref_dictionary.asp">Dictionary Methods</a></p>
<p><a href="python_ref_tuple.asp">Tuple Methods</a></p>
<p><a href="python_ref_set.asp">Set Methods</a></p>
<p><a href="python_ref_file.asp">File Methods</a></p>
<p><a href="python_ref_keywords.asp">Python Keywords</a></p>
<hr>
<h2>Download Python</h2>
<p>Download Python from the official Python web site:
  <a target="_blank" href="https://python.org/">https://python.org</a></p>
<hr>

<h2>Python Exam - Get Your Diploma!</h2>
<div class="w3-row">
<div class="w3-third w3-container w3-padding-24"><a href="/cert/default.asp"><img src="/images/w3certified_logo_250.png" style="max-width:100%;" alt="W3Schools Certification"></a> </div>
<div class="w3-twothird w3-container"><h2>W3Schools' Online Certification</h2>
<p>The perfect solution for professionals who need to balance work, family, and career building.</p>
<p>More than 25 000 certificates already issued!</p>
</div>
</div>
<p><a class="w3-btn" href="/cert/default.asp">Get Your Certificate »</a></p>
<p style="clear:both;">The <a href="/cert/default.asp">HTML Certificate</a> documents your knowledge of HTML.</p>
<p>The <a href="/cert/default.asp">CSS Certificate</a> documents your knowledge of advanced CSS.</p>
<p>The <a href="/cert/default.asp">JavaScript Certificate</a> documents your knowledge of JavaScript and HTML DOM.</p>
<p>The <a href="/cert/default.asp">Python Certificate</a> documents your knowledge of Python.</p>
<p>The <a href="/cert/default.asp">jQuery Certificate</a> documents your knowledge of jQuery.</p>
<p>The <a href="/cert/default.asp">SQL Certificate</a> documents your knowledge of SQL.</p>
<p>The <a href="/cert/default.asp">PHP Certificate</a> documents your knowledge of PHP and MySQL.</p>
<p>The <a href="/cert/default.asp">XML Certificate</a> documents your knowledge of XML, XML DOM and XSLT.</p>
<p>The <a href="/cert/default.asp">Bootstrap Certificate</a> documents your knowledge of the Bootstrap framework.</p>


<div class="w3-clear nextprev">
<a class="w3-left w3-btn" href="/default.asp">❮ Home</a>
<a class="w3-right w3-btn" href="python_intro.asp">Next ❯</a>
</div>
</div>
```**strong text**
````

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I get this straight, but if you whant just adjust the content, you can use only css to do this,  you can organize your content in "Div Blocks" and set the same class to each one and instead of hr just put a border-bottom like this

```css
#main{ max-width:1170px;  margin: 0 auto;}
.bg_block{ width:100%; border-bottom: 1px solid #666; padding: 20px; box-sizing: border-box;}
```

```html
 <div id='main'>
  <div class='bg_block'>
   <div class="w3-clear nextprev">
   <a class="w3-left w3-btn" href="/default.asp">❮ Home</a>
   <a class="w3-right w3-btn" href="python_intro.asp">Next ❯</a>
   </div>

   <div class="w3-panel w3-info intro">
   <p>Python is a programming language.</p>
   <p>Python can be used on a server to create web applications.</p>
   <a class="w3-btn w3-margin-bottom" href="python_intro.asp">Start learning Python now »</a>
   </div>
  </div><!--bg_block-->
    </div><!--main-->
```